# Ionic - select on 'focus' with CSS

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Is there a way to know via CSS when a `<ion-select>` element is on focus?

I'm trying to create a similar google animation inputs where you click and the label and it goes into the border, and I was able to successfully do it with `ion-input`, by using the class `.item-has-focus` but with `ion-select` I'm having some issues to detect when to know it's focused without using JavaScript.

Is there a way to achieve this without having to change my element and using a regular `<select>`?

My Code:

```
*HTML*
<ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label class="label-class">Where is your location?</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="popover" name="location" ngControl="location">
       <ion-select-option *ngFor="let location of locations" value="{{location.value}}">{{location.text}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

*CSS*
.label-class{
   color: #a6a5a5;
   pointer-events: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(50% - 25px);
   left: 10px;
   transition: all 0.1s linear;
   background-color: white;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 4px;
   padding-right: 4px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 15px;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

This make the label to be readable inside the input, but when people click on it (on focus) I want to move it up.

Comment: I assume the element uses shadow DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using CSS

```
<ion-select class="ion-select-class"> What ever your select code and options are </ion-select>


In .scss file,

ion-select.ion-select-class:focus {
  // Manipulate your css here
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of your code so that we can see whats happening?

Comment: I added my code, which shows the HTML and CSS and explains that the label is "readable" inside the select, but the wanted animation is for when you click on it to go up, if possible without JS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working:

```
ion-select:active {
  background-color: red
}
```